# JSON structure for jQuery each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I can't seem to work out how to use jQuery to manipulate my JSON.  I have an ajax query that is correctly replying with some key/value pairs that are to be used as select options.

```
[{"Value":"???","Text":"??? - Unknown"},
{"Value":"AAA","Text":"AAA - A Company"},
{"Value":"BBB","Text":"BBB - B Company"},
{"Value":"CCC","Text":"CCC - C Company"},
{"Value":"DDD","Text":"DDD - D Company"},
{"Value":"EEE","Text":"EEE - E Company"},
{"Value":"FFF","Text":"FFF - F Company"}]
```

My jQuery is as follows

```
$(function () {

    $("#sqlServerControl").change(function () {
        var sqlServer = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/ReportGroupsHelper/Ajax/GetOrganisationData.cshtml",
            type: "GET",
            data: "sqlserver=" + sqlServer,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var options, index, select, option;

                // Get the raw DOM object for the select box
                select = $("#organisationControl");

                // Clear the old options
                if (select.options != null) {
                    select.options.length = 0;
                }

                // Load the new options
                //options = data.options;
                //for (index = 0; index < options.length; ++index) {
                //    option = options[index];
                //    select.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value));
                //}

                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    select.append($("<option/>", {
                        value: key,
                        text: value
                    }));
                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```

You can see where I tried a different method, now commented out.  Currently it hits the `$.each` and then skips past.  The html for the target control is just

```
    <fieldset>
        <label for="organisationControl">Organisation</label>
        <select name="organisation" id="organisationControl"></select>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: You need `{
      value: value.Value,
      text: value.Text
    }`

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the current data? Are you sure that you're matching the correct element? Anyway, your html creation is probably not gonna work if you're not modyfing the text you're inserting, currently you're gonna have [Object Object]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` is not the value you are looking for in `each()`. You need to use `value.Value` and `value.Text`.

```js
var data = [{"Value":"???","Text":"??? - Unknown"},
{"Value":"AAA","Text":"AAA - A Company"},
{"Value":"BBB","Text":"BBB - B Company"},
{"Value":"CCC","Text":"CCC - C Company"},
{"Value":"DDD","Text":"DDD - D Company"},
{"Value":"EEE","Text":"EEE - E Company"},
{"Value":"FFF","Text":"FFF - F Company"}];

var options, index, select, option;

// Get the raw DOM object for the select box
select = $("#organisationControl");

// Clear the old options
if (select.options != null) {
    select.options.length = 0;
}

// Load the new options
//options = data.options;
//for (index = 0; index < options.length; ++index) {
//    option = options[index];
//    select.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value));
//}

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    select.append($("<option/>", {
        value: value.Value,
        text: value.Text
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <label for="organisationControl">Organisation</label>
    <select name="organisation" id="organisationControl"></select>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$.each()`, the callback's parameters are the index and the element.

```
$.each(data, function(i, option) {
  select.append($("<option/>", {
    value: option.Value,
    text: option.Text
  }));
});
```

I suggest changing the JSON keys to lowercase, that way you can use

```
$.each(data, function(i, option) {
  select.append($("<option/>", option));
});
```